# One set of categories for multiple custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

Hi I have a site which has 3 different custom post types.

At the moment each post type has it own custom taxonomy which is linked to the post type like a native category.

What I would like is one custom taxonomy which links to all three post types.

Comment: What are the custom post type names ? and what do you mean by one set of categories, do you mean one taxonomy ?

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Added more info.  Hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is, instead of using different taxonomies per post type, use one shared/common between them. You're setting up the post type to taxonomy relation either via the `taxonomies` parameter of [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) or per usage of [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type), just change this, after reading the documentation, according to your needs.